# Migrate a query from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have the following query written for Oracle

```
SELECT  max(POS) keep (dense_rank last order by LASTDATE)       as POSITION
FROM TEST
```

How can I modify it to sql server?

Comment: This is not PL/SQL - just normal oracle SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, your query is effectively just getting the POS for the latest LASTDATE.  You can rewrite this in TSQL like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 POS
FROM TEST
ORDER BY LASTDATE DESC
```